# Merging OD Cost Distance Matrix result from ArcGIS Network Analyst in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, merge

Using ArcGIS 10 Network Analyst, I've created small python script that calculates OD matrix between certain locations, i.e. not between each origin and destination but for each origin I have a set of destinations that I want to calculate routes for. I end up with 17 results saved as a .lyr file (don't necessary need to save them on hard drive as such). I would like to merge those results together. The problem is a OD Cost Matrix Layer is in fact a group of layers and I'm only interested in layer Lines.

To sum up: if layer is OD Cost Matrix Layer (group of layers) and Lines is one of the layer in that group and I want to use Merge tool to merge a few of such Lines layers - how do I do it as

```
arcpy.Merge_management(layer, output)
```

is obviously giving me an error of input not being a table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to merge those layers I need a list of OD layer names with "\Lines" added to them. Something like that

```
layers = ["ODlayer1\Lines", "ODlayer2\Lines", "ODlayer3\Lines"]
arcpy.Merge_management(layers, output)
```